# Reuse ADOQuery after cancellation

Tags: delphi, ado, delphi-2010

I am using Asynchrounous ADO queries in my Delphi 2010 app.  The user can request cancellation of a query, or it may fail due to an error.  This is the code I am using to cancel the query:

```
if not Assigned(myADOQuery.Recordset) then exit;
if stFetching in myADOQuery.RecordsetState then begin
  fCommand := _Command(myADOQuery.Recordset.ActiveCommand);
  fCommand.Cancel;
  if Assigned(myADOQuery.Recordset) then myADOQuery.Recordset.Cancel;
end;
if Assigned(myADOQuery.Recordset) then myADOQuery.Recordset.Cancel;
StatusBar1.Panels[2].Text := '';
//ShowMessage('Query Cancelled');
myADOQuery.Close;
```

I am using the ADOConnection ExecuteComplete to show the cancellation (or other error) to the user:

```
if EventStatus = esErrorsOccured then ShowMessage(Error.Description);
```

I now want to be able to re-use the query after it has been amended, but when I re-run it I get the same error message.  Is there a way I can reset the query (including the SQL.Text) and running it again?

NiMuSi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *think* your problem may be with your query's Connection object.

An AdoConnection has an `Errors` collection which records details of each ADO error that occurs.  Iirc, this collection accumulates as objects using the AdoConnection encounter execution errors, until you call `Clear` on the Errors interface.  It may be that cancelling the query execution is causing the error on its next execution.

So, try the following before attempting to re-use your AdoQuery:

```
myAdoQuery.Connection.Errors.Clear;
```

and let us know how you get on.

Also, if I were you I would test for the AdoQuery's RecordSet being NIL before attempting to re-open it And explicitly set it to NIL at the end of your cancellation routine.  Just in case ...

Comment: Thanks very much @MartynA, that did it.